# Pandas Erratic Sorting by DateTime column

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe, and after reading some comments (thank you) would like to clarify.

I have defined my BeginDate column as

```
data['BeginDate'] = pd.to_datetime(data.BeginDate)
data = data.sort_values(['BeginDate'], ascending = [False])
```

by printing type(data['BeginDate']) it returns

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

BeginDate           X
11/18/2017 5:00     2780.784
11/18/2017 6:00     2652.312
11/18/2017 7:00     2596.198
11/18/2017 8:00     2573.241
11/18/2017 9:00     2601.293
11/18/2017 10:00    2803.294
11/18/2017 11:00    2964.356
11/18/2017 12:00    3117.072
11/18/2017 13:00    3254.652
11/19/2017 5:00     2446.695
11/19/2017 6:00     2301.853
11/19/2017 7:00     2204.87
11/19/2017 8:00     2188.789
11/19/2017 9:00     2162.051
11/19/2017 10:00    2289.19
11/19/2017 11:00    2317.428
11/19/2017 12:00    2501.4
11/19/2017 13:00    2686.298
11/19/2017 14:00    2889.88
11/19/2017 15:00    3032.894
11/19/2017 16:00    3027.868
11/19/2017 17:00    3077.443
11/19/2017 18:00    3006.568
11/19/2017 19:00    3046.463
11/19/2017 20:00    3085.442
11/19/2017 21:00    3308.473
11/19/2017 22:00    3679.34
11/19/2017 23:00    3664.858
11/20/2017 0:00     3577.343
11/20/2017 1:00     3385.539
11/20/2017 2:00     3146.491
11/20/2017 3:00     2954.23
11/20/2017 4:00     2676.333
```

and I try to attempt to sort this data by 'BeginDate' column, in a descending fashion as follows

```
data = data.sort_values(['BeginDate'], ascending = [False])
```

However by doing so, not only does it fail, but it jumbles the data into a sort which makes no sense to me.

```
BeginDate           X
11/19/2017 5:00     2446.695
11/19/2017 6:00     2301.853
11/19/2017 7:00     2204.87
11/19/2017 8:00     2188.789
11/19/2017 9:00     2162.051
11/19/2017 10:00    2289.19
11/19/2017 11:00    2317.428
11/19/2017 12:00    2501.4
11/19/2017 13:00    2686.298
11/19/2017 14:00    2889.88
11/19/2017 15:00    3032.894
11/19/2017 16:00    3027.868
11/19/2017 17:00    3077.443
11/19/2017 18:00    3006.568
11/19/2017 19:00    3046.463
11/19/2017 20:00    3085.442
11/19/2017 21:00    3308.473
11/19/2017 22:00    3679.34
11/19/2017 23:00    3664.858
11/20/2017 0:00     3577.343
11/20/2017 1:00     3385.539
11/20/2017 2:00     3146.491
11/20/2017 3:00     2954.23
11/20/2017 4:00     2676.333
11/18/2017 5:00     2780.784
11/18/2017 6:00     2652.312
11/18/2017 7:00     2596.198
11/18/2017 8:00     2573.241
11/18/2017 9:00     2601.293
11/18/2017 10:00    2803.294
11/18/2017 11:00    2964.356
11/18/2017 12:00    3117.072
11/18/2017 13:00    3254.652
```

Im unsure what could be causing this to happen, and so far as I can tell my BeginDate column is now formatted correctly. Thanks in advance for your help!

As requested in comments, print(data.info()) yields

```
BeginDate                  72 non-null datetime64[ns]
X                          72 non-null float64
```

Comment: What is `data.columns` giving?

Comment: It makes a perfect sense if your `BeginDate` column is of `object` (string) dtype - in this case it's sorted lexicographically

Comment: as @MaxU pointed out, your `BeginDate` column is stored as a string. convert to a date using `df['BeginDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df.BeginDate)`

Comment: Thanks all, I have edited the post. I defined the BeginDate column initially as you had suggested, so I am unsure what else could be wrong. Thanks

Comment: @FrankDrin can you use `data.to_dict()` to generate the dataset that we all can use?

Comment: Can you post the output of `data.info()`. What is X in your sample? Where does it come from?

Comment: @FrankDrin I cannot reproduce your output on my computer.

Comment: X is the output of a json files, which looped through to create the pandas table

Comment: Please don't modify or trim the outputs. At the top it says "<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>" but under that you are listing two columns. `data.info()` is supposed to give info about the index, too but it is discarded from the sample output as well as `data.info()`.

Comment: Its a massive data set, and im sorry as a novice, but I dont know the best way to ask for help with a pandas frame that hs 30 columns.... What do I do ?

Comment: Create a new DataFrame containing relevant columns and paste its output. For example, `data[['BeginDate', 'X']].info()`